# Rudimentary Maze Game

Tags: java, maze

Today in my class, we discussed a rudimentary maze game that could be built in Java. Honestly, I have no idea how to go about creating something like this and the Professor was not much hep either. Nevertheless, I want to know how to make something like this, without sing arrays. As a very much noob at coding, I have a very vague idea onto where I should start. Please help me! As I would look to see the code behind this which generated the map. Note: with each command the code looped back and much (R) to a new section on the grid after a choice was stated by the user. Thanks!

Help Robot (R) get to Exit (E)

R o o o o

o o o o o

o o o o o

o o o o o

o o o o E

1. up
2. down
3. left
4. right

Move? 4

Comment: I suggest you try and implement as much as you can. I assume you can do a Hello World program and know how to print something, and input a numebr etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you cannot use array and cannot create any new method. You can do something like this:

**Output:**

```
 R  .  .  .  . 
 .  .  .  .  . 
 .  .  .  .  . 
 .  .  .  .  . 
 .  .  .  .  E
```

**Codes:**

```
    int playerX=0, playerY=0;  //holds player's location
    int exitX = 4, exitY = 4;  //holds exit's location

    //Print map
    for(int x=0; x<5; x++){
        for(int y=0; y<5; y++)
            if(x == playerX && y == playerY)
                System.out.print(" R "); //print player location
            else if(x == exitX && y == exitY)
                System.out.print(" E ");
            else    
                System.out.print(" . ");
        System.out.println("");     
    }
    /*
    //Update player's position on movement
    if (movement == DOWN)
        playerY = Math.min(playerY+1 , 5);
    else if (movement == UP)
        playerY = Math.max(playerY-1 , 0);
    else if (movement == LEFT)
        playerX = Math.max(playerX-1 , 0);
    else else if (movement == RIGHT)
        playerX = Math.max(playerY+1 , 5);  
    */
```

You can enclose every thing in a while loop, and repeat the loop so long player's location is not same as exit's location.